# How to prevent Chrome from blocking ZIP downloads from my Javascript script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, zip

I'm working on an application that consists entirely of Javascript files that run on the client. My application requests a bunch of images and displays them to the user. Then, I have a function that allows the user to download all the images into a zip file by using the client-zip library https://github.com/Touffy/client-zip version 2.4.4.

I tried testing it out, and the ZIP file was created, but Chrome blocked the download, saying it is dangerous. All I have in my ZIP file (I hope) is .png, .jpg, .jpeg, etc image files and possibly some gifs. No executables, no javascript files, no .swf, no nothing. How can I get Chrome to stop blocking my ZIP downloads?

This isn't a problem with my browser either because I'm able to download ZIP files from github and other sites with no problem.

EDIT: I'm not quite sure if my images are being downloaded properly. It's possible that all my ZIP files are empty, if that changes anything

Comment: Is your site https or http and yes, content is important so test that first

Comment: It runs on the client. The server sends you all the javascript files, and then the user interacts with the application and downloads images using these files. Also, I'm testing locally on my own computer right now.

Comment: So it is from file:/// ? Chrome will acct differently depending on origin

Comment: @mplungjan The URL starts with C:/ for C drive, but I believe it's the same thing yeah

Comment: you should always test from a server such as `localhost` and never from `file:` or `C:` !

Comment: So that is the issue. Run from an https:// server and not the local file system

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found the problem. No, it wasn't because I was running my program locally. In fact it's because my ZIP file was empty! After I got my code to actually put files in, I was able to download the ZIP file safely.

This seemed stupid of Chrome to mark an empty ZIP file as dangerous, so I did an experiment. I edited my ZIP file creator function, so that it emptied my file array. So, imageFiles = []. Then, I tested my code again, and BOOM, my zip file was declared a threat like before.

So, the issue was that my code had a bug in it, which caused the ZIP file I created to be empty. And chrome (at least the version I'm running Version 114.0.5735.134 (Official Build) (64-bit)) marks empty ZIP files as dangerous.